# JavaScript destructure an object to another object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

```
let x = {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 30
};
```

Is there any way to make only a,b keys of x as another object?

```
let y = x; //someway here through Object destructing

console.log(y); //{a:10,b:20}
```

Comment: Not natively through destructuring alone, you'll have to use a function like `pick`

Comment: Also you can use lodash's omit or pick functions which are a bit cleaner for this

Comment: You can do it this way `let {c, ...y} = x`